# Call functions from array into table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, random

I am trying to call several functions which contain simple math problems using a random number into an array then into a table.  I think I am close, I am just unsure of how to write the table. I have as follows:

HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table id="content">
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function RandX(){

var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
}

function RandY(){                       
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
}



var math1 = function(x,y) {return x * y;};  
var math2 = function(x,y) {return x + 1;};
var math3 = function(x,y) {return x/y;};
var math4 = function(x,y) {return x % y;};
var math5 = function(x,y) {return math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2);};
var math6 = function(x,y) {return x^2;};
var math7 = function(x,y) {return (10*x) + (y/2);};
var math8 = function(x,y) {return SIGMA)

var maths = [];

maths.push(math1);
maths.push(math2);
maths.push(math3);
maths.push(math4);
maths.push(math5);
maths.push(math6);
maths.push(math7);
maths.push(math8);
//maths[0](RandX,2);//return RandX* RandY
//maths[1](3,4);//12 - put random numbners here?



 var c = document.getElementById("Content");
 var content = document.createElement("tr");
 for( var i = 0; i < maths.length; i++ ){
  var d = document.createElement("<td>" + "</td>);
  d.innerHTML = "<td>" + maths[0](RandX(), RandY()) + "</td>"; 
  content.appendChild(d);
 }
 c.appendChild(content);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I shouild have commented out SIGMA btw

Comment: The *rand* functions don't return any value. Also, you are attempting to insert a TD as the content of a TD, which is invalid HTML. Lastly, you can't use innerHTML to modify a table in IE, you must either write an entire table or just the content of a cell.

Comment: you cant at all in IE?  Thanks I didn't know that!

Comment: Call what? innerHTML is a property that can be read and set, it isn't callable. In IE you can't modify the innerHTML of a table, table section (head, body, foot) or table row element. You can only modify the innerHTML of a cell (TD and TH).

Comment: i said can't at all not call yeah just found that interesting thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the items and add them to the table like this:

```
var contentDiv = document.getElementById("Content");
var row = document.createElement("tr");
for( var i = 0; i < maths.length; i++ ){
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.innerHTML = maths[i]; 
    content.appendChild(cell);
}
contentDiv.appendChild(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in the script - here is the correct one:

http://jsfiddle.net/wMF5M/

```
function RandX(){
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    return x;
}

function RandY(){                       
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    return y;
}

var math1 = function(x,y) {return x * y;};  
var math2 = function(x,y) {return x + 1;};
var math3 = function(x,y) {return x/y;};
var math4 = function(x,y) {return x % y;};
var math5 = function(x,y) {return math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2);};
var math6 = function(x,y) {return x^2;};
var math7 = function(x,y) {return (10*x) + (y/2);};
var math8 = function(x,y) {return SIGMA;}

var maths = [];

maths.push(math1);
maths.push(math2);
maths.push(math3);
maths.push(math4);
maths.push(math5);
maths.push(math6);
maths.push(math7);
maths.push(math8);
//maths[0](RandX,2);//return RandX* RandY
//maths[1](3,4);//12 - put random numbners here?



 var content = document.getElementById("content");
 var tr = document.createElement("tr");
 for( var i = 0; i < maths.length; i++ ){
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerHTML =  + maths[0](RandX(), RandY());
  tr.appendChild(td);
 }
 content.appendChild(tr);
```

Comment: I keep getting a 
TypeError: content is null
[Break On This Error]  

content.appendChild(tr);

Comment: any idea? i am using firebug as a debugger

Comment: Look at my link - there is the full solution [http://jsfiddle.net/wMF5M/](http://jsfiddle.net/wMF5M/) - if content is null it means it does not exist in your page - content is the html element

Comment: Gotcha, I did exactly that but have my <table> tag inside the <body> which should be fine right?

Comment: yepp - you need to define it in the body

Comment: Sorry how do you do that? I'm very new at this.  Why wouldnt <body> <table id="content" border="1"> </table> </body> work? Its looking for the id of content alone right?  By the above html, I mean that is what I have currently, which isn't working.

Comment: Yes - just look at the link - jsfiddle puts the body tag automtically - what are you getting trouble at ?

Comment: Yep, I have exactly that, all my debugger keeps saying is content is null and refers to line 42 when appending the tr

Comment: Also I'd be happy to mark you I just don't know how to do that haha Ill figure it out, I just joined stack overflow

Comment: do you have the `var content = document.getElementById("content");` code ?

Comment: yeah  var content = document.getElementById("content"); exactly, I must be doign something wrong in my html

Comment: ive got: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

   <table id="content" border="1">
    </table>

</body>
</html>

Comment: and where is your javascript ?

Comment: its linked with <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> I'm pretty sure that works because it shows up in the debugger and also references the script

Comment: want me to do jsfiddle or upload the .html and js

Comment: You didn't include script.js - best to make jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

These function need to return a value. Since they are identical other than the name, there doesn't seem much point in two functions:

```
function RandX(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
}

function RandY(){                       
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
}
```

the functions that are assigned to variables, then pushed into an array can be simply assigned in an array literal:

```
var maths = [
    function(x,y) {return x * y;},
    function(x,y) {return x + 1;},
    function(x,y) {return x/y;},
    function(x,y) {return x % y;},
    function(x,y) {return math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2);},
    function(x,y) {return x^2;},
    function(x,y) {return (10*x) + (y/2);},
    function(x,y) {return SIGMA)
];

 var c = document.getElementById("Content");
 var content = document.createElement("tr");
 for( var i = 0; i < maths.length; i++ ){

   // The argument for createElement is the tagname, not markup
   var d = document.createElement('td');
```

You can't assign a TD as the content of a TD. And since this is just text, better to create a text node and insert that. Also, you want to call a different function each time, so use `i`:

```
   d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(maths[i](RandX(), RandY()))); 
 }

// In IE, you must append rows to a table section element, (thead, tfoot or tbody):
c.tBodies[0].appendChild(content);
```

HTH.

Comment: I see, I haven't used createtextnode yet I'll look it up thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/Jra9w/1/

```
//You don't need 2 different functions to execute the same logic, so here
//RandX and RandY are combined into randNum
function randNum() {

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);

}

//Instead of instanciating the array and then pushing the functions into 
//it you can instanciate the array already initialized with a set of items.
var maths = [
        function (x, y) { return x * y; },
        function (x, y) { return x + 1; },
        function (x, y) { return x / y; },
        function (x, y) { return x * y; },
        function (x, y) { return Math.sqrt(x^2 + y^2); },
        function (x, y) { return x^2; },
        function (x, y) { return (10 * x) + (y / 2); },
        function (x, y) { 
            //SIGMA is not defined in your code and I am
            //not sure what you want to do in here. This function will throw
            //an error if you try to return the undeclared SIGMA variable

            //return SIGMA;
        }
    ],
    i = 0,
    len = maths.length,

    //JavaScript is a case-sensitive language so you must write the id exactly as defined
    //in the id attribute of the html element
    tableElement = document.getElementById('content'),
    results = [];

//Note that we have cached the maths.length result into the 'len' variable instead of
//putting it directly into the loop condition. The reason for this is that the condition //will be evaluated on each iterations and property lookups are expensive in JavaScript, so 
//we try to reduce them.

for (; i < len; i++) {
    //we push all the results into a new array
    results.push(maths[i](randNum(), randNum()));
}

//Array.join is faster for concatenating strings that using the + operator when you want to 
//concatenate a lot of strings together.
tableElement.innerHTML = '<tr><td>' + results.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>';
```